# Cannot use two glare nodes at the same time

Tags: compositing-nodes, glare

I am trying to use two glares in the compositor, and it works in viewport, but on render and compositor view only one works.

Screenshot shows desired output on the left and render output on the right, where the fog glow does not render.I also tried running them in parallel then using a mix node instead of in chain, but the result is the same.

Both viewport and render are 1024 samples Cycle, no denoising. Using RTX2080 on Blender 4.0.2

Thanks in advance for your help ! [image: screenshot]

Comment: Having 2 times a glare node with mix at 0 doesn't make much sense. It means your 2nd glare is applied to the image + the 1st glare node. Try inputing your render layer to both your glare, then combined them with a mix node (screen or add) or an alpha over. At least one of the glare should be at mix 1.